# lib2to3 Architecture Documentation

Tags: python, documentation

I want to get a feel for [`lib2to3`](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) but can't find much in the way of documentation.  Has anything in the way of an architecture overview been written?  Where can I find more information on the library?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The only documentation that I am aware of (apart from the [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/lib2to3)), is Lennart Regebro's excellent [Porting to Python 3](http://python3porting.com/) book (online in full).

The book has a [full chapter on writing your own `lib2to3` fixers](http://python3porting.com/fixers.html). The chapter discusses the parse tree architucture used by `lib2to3` and how to take advantage of that structure to create your own translations to be run when porting code from python 2 to 3.